# crystal reports : global subreport variable sum not transferring to parent main report

Tags: crystal-reports, subreport

I am running crystal reports 11 and in the main report is a subreport which calculates the balance.  In the subreport balance, I have the formula named balancetotal which manually sums the running total of the tarinvoice.balance field.

```
WhileReadingRecords;
global numbervar balancetotal;
balancetotal := balancetotal + {tarInvoice.Balance}
```

In the main parent report, i have a formula named balancetotal with this formula:

```
    global numbervar balancetotal;
    balancetotal;
```

is this incorrect?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

nevermind.  I'm supposed to use "shared" instead of "global"